# Why does this paper report potential energy in kHz, and what does it mean?

Tags: potential, potential-energy, units

I am interested in studying theoretically the double well system shown in the figure below, which shows an experimental demonstration of an atomtronic battery.

> [image]
>
> Caption: Figure 1. (a) Schematic of the double-well atomtronic battery system. The top panel shows the longitudinal potential energy landscape. A resonant 'terminator' beam removes atoms that flow into the load well from the system. The bottom panel shows a false color in situ absorption image of atoms occupying both wells of the potential. (b) Thévenin equivalent circuit representation of the atomtronic battery. Analogous circuit properties are labeled in (a) and (b): electromotive force ε, internal resistance Rint, atom current IL, terminal voltage VT, and load resistance RL. The dashed portion of the circuit represents the terminator beam as a lumped element that is always impedance matched to the battery internal resistance.
>
> Experimental demonstration of an atomtronic battery. SC Caliga, CJE Straatsma and DZ Anderson. [*New J. Phys.* **19**, 013036 (2017)](https://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1367-2630/aa56d8).

I want to reproduce the described double well in terms of theoretical formula. Potential is usually expressed in joules or electronvolts, but here it is in kHz.

Why is the potential expressed in kHz the previous figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, that paper uses units where Planck's constant $h$ has been set to one. More practically, this means that whenever an energy is presented as $V=\{V\}\:\mathrm{kHz}$, what it means is that its real value is $V=h\times\{V\}\:\mathrm{kHz}$, i.e. the energy given by that frequency through Planck's relation $E=h\nu$.

This can be seen directly from the paper, if you actually read with due care: the first occurrence of this usage, on page 3, comes with a footnote,

> Throughout this paper, the unit convention of [9] is followed, and both energies and particle currents are reported in units of Hz,

which refers you to [*Phys. Rev. A* **88**, 043641 (2013)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.88.043641), which then states

> The results are presented in frequency units obtained by dividing the chemical potentials by $h$, where $h$ is Planck’s constant.

In a similar vein, the usage $T=14.13(50)\:\mathrm{kHz}$ in page 4 should be understood through units in which the Boltzmann constant is $k_B=1$, i.e. it actually means $T=k_B h \times 14.13(50)\:\mathrm{kHz}$.

Comment: As h is chosen to be one so can we say that V  in Joules has same value as V expressed in kHz?

Comment: @Sam Not really - if you really insist on going down that route, you can say that $h=6.626\times 10^{-34}\mathrm{J\:s}=1$ so therefore $1\:\mathrm{Hz}=6.626\times 10^{-34}\mathrm{J}$, but that's a pretty crass way of doing things, I think. It's rather more accurate to say that we identify energies and frequencies so deeply that we no longer bother using different symbols for the two: we might call it $V$ and say it's a potential energy, and then quote the equivalent frequency, because there's a one to one correspondence between frequencies and energies and there's no ambiguity.

Comment: Alright. Many thaks